# Javascript: Weird behaviour with += operator

Tags: javascript, operators

I know the title is somewhat vague, but I'm not sure how to really explain this. So, in code

```
var a= 2, b=3;
a+=b;
//5
```

This is pretty basic javascript. Now I want to check if the result is larger than a certain number

```
var a= 2, b=3, c=4;
(a+=b) >= c;
//true
```

However, if I forget to add the parenthesis, I don't understand where the result could possible come from

```
var a= 2, b=3, c=4;
a += b >= c;
//2
```

I tried reading some stuff about order of operations and whatnot, but I still can't understand how that code can possibly output "2"

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because

```
a += b >= c;
```

is

```
a += (b >= c);
```

which is (in your case)

```
a += (false);
```

which ends up being

```
a += 0;
```

which is `a`.

The right-hand side of all of the assignment operators is evaluated before anything is done with the result. So `b >= c` is evaluated, giving us `false`, which is coerced to `0` when you try to treat it as a number with `a +=`.